# Failover chat search index out of date

Tags: bug, chat, search

I recently did [this search](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Welcome&Room=111347&User=4099593&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest), and notice it's not picking up newer results (Last one was from Jul 29 2017):

[image]

I know for a fact this user has said welcome recently: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41021534#41021534

It appears that this was an issue that was posted [here](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/958348801315627008). Can we make it so that failover indexes stay synced with the main site in case of future failovers?

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/958348801315627008

Comment: I'm pretty sure due to the search failover the index in Denver has to catch up

Comment: Not just on Stack Overflow chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%40duga+is+alive&room=20298 vs. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42577233#42577233

Comment: @rene Seems like you were right, it seems to have caught up again.

Comment: @SimonForsberg you dare to doubt me ...???

Comment: @rene Well, you did delete your answer

Comment: Well, you didn't seem to be satisfied with it

Comment: @rene I was very satisfied with it. So satisfied, I've updated my question. <3

Comment: It is better answered by SE staff. They are more trustworthy.